# Powershell Azure CmdletInvocationException

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I have a problem with using Powershell for Azure. What I have is a small C# console application from where I am running Powershell Azure commands.

This is my code:

```
public class PowerShellService : IDisposable
{
    private PowerShell _shellInstance;
    private PSDataCollection<PSObject> _outputCollection;
    private Runspace rs;

    public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs> Data;
    public event EventHandler<ErrorRecordEventArgs> Error;

    public PowerShellService()
    {
        InitializeShellInstance();
    }

    private void InitializeShellInstance()
    {
        InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        string[] modules = new string[] { "Full path to Azure.psd1", "Full path to AzureRM.psd1" };
        iss.ImportPSModule(modules);

        _shellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
        string initializationScript = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned";
        _shellInstance.AddScript(initializationScript);
        _shellInstance.Invoke();

        rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
        rs.Open();
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Exception occurs on line: `rs.Open()`

The exception is as follows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Additional information: Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.AzureRMCmdlet' threw an exception."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I reinstalled everything related to Azure and then it worked